# Derivation of memorylessness of Exponential distribution

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, inference

I came across this information in Statistical Inference by Casella and Berger. The problem was the authors didn’t explain how they derived the second equality (highlighted). I never saw such an expression as $P(X > s, X > t)$. Also, why was it divided by $P(X > t)$? Was it because this was the case of [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability)? Could you please tell me the logic of that derivation? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=memorylessness+exponential. However, the second equality is simply a *definition* of conditional probability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably familiar with the rule and just don't recognize it in this setting. It applies to densities...

$f(x|y)=\frac{f(x,y)}{f(y)}$

...but also to sets (which is your case)...

$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$

In words, a conditional thing equals the joint thing over the marginal of the condition. This follows from the ["chain rule"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_(probability)).

Comment: Thanks, Alvaro. To clarify, did *the rule* as mentioned in your first sentence refer to *conditional probability*? If so, I wonder why the authors didn't say it, and should had used the expression $P(A \cap B)$ instead?

Comment: Yes, it's a factorization of conditional probability. $P(A\cap B)$ is set notation and $P(A,B)$ is probability notation (I fixed that in my answer now, sorry), but they signify the same thing.